# System.InvalidCastException: System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, exception

Am getting an exception randomly. I have a barcode scanner which enters barcodes into a table. The code is written in C#. I was able to get the exception twice at first; however, am no longer able to generate it. The exception is System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'. I generated it at first by scanning 2 different water bottles, 2-3 times each. Then when I hit the save button, I got the exception. I tried Google for researching if someone else has got this error before, but could not find anyone with similar issue in same context. The exception is thrown in the following code segment:

```
 foreach (object o in this.theBindingSource.List)
 {
   System.Data.DataRowView dataRowView1 = (System.Data.DataRowView)o;
 }
```

Apparently, sometimes, o is of type System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor and not of type System.Data.DataRowView. Any ideas why this exception is thrown?

The BindingSource is being populated by the database:

```
  XYZDataAccess.TypedDataSets.ABCTag tags
                = XYZDataAccess.DAL.ABCTagDAL.GetABCTags(
                    DeliverySession.DeliverySessionId);
            if (tags != null && tags.Tables[0] != null)
            {
                theBindingSource.Sort = "";
                theBindingSource.DataSource = tags;
            }
```

The reason I had to loop through the binding source is that another DataGridView needs to be populated with the contents of the bindindg source; furthermore, the DataGridView implemented a custom sorting for the data in the control or view. In addition to removing the direct access of the List should I specify the DisplayMember property?

Comment: How are you populating your BindingSource?

Comment: The BindingSource is being populated by the database:
<pre>
  XYZDataAccess.TypedDataSets.ABCTag tags
                = XYZDataAccess.DAL.ABCTagDAL.GetABCTags(
                    DeliverySession.DeliverySessionId);
            if (tags != null && tags.Tables[0] != null)
            {
                theBindingSource.Sort = "";
                theBindingSource.DataSource = tags;
            }
</pre>

Comment: I am getting the same error in a DataGridView.CellFormatting event - I expect a row's DataBoundItem to be a DataRowView but instead it is a DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor. I have no idea why this happens, but the trigger seemed to be that I changed my BindingSource.DataSource from a typed DataSet to null, and then later set it to a valid typed DataSet again. Changing the DataSource back to a typed DataSet caused the error. To avoid the error, I refrain from setting the DataSource to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor** is a valid result from a BindingSource, especially if the item being bound to doesn't specify the .DisplayMember properly.  Is there a particular reason why you are manually looping through the binding source?  The purpose of the binding source is that you can bind it to specific controls and have them automatically populated from the database.

Anyway, I haven't tested the following code, but you may have better luck with:

```
foreach (object o in this.theBindingSource)
{
    System.Data.DataRowView dataRowView1 = (System.Data.DataRowView)o;
}
```

BindingSource is already IEnumerable, so you shouldn't have to directly access the list.

**UPDATE**

Instead of looping through, you could do something like this to populate your DataGridView like:

```
theBindingSource.DataSource = tags;
yourDataGridView.DataSource = theBindingSource;
```

I believe .DisplayMember is only necessary on things like ListViews, but I'm not positive about that.

Comment: The reason I had to loop through the binding source is that another DataGridView needs to be populated with the contents of the bindindg source; furthermore, the DataGridView implemented a custom sorting for the data in the control or view. In addition to removing the direct access of the List should I specify the DisplayMember property?

Comment: Why would a BindingSource contain DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor instead of DataRowViews?